# How to add multiple link styles on the same page?

Tags: css, hyperlink, dreamweaver

I have two hyperlinks on a page. I'm happy with the css on 'link1' (white text / red rollover) however I want to have a different styling for 'link2'.

I've created a seperate css for this section and have managed to colour it green but I can't get rid of the red rollover effect?

Does anyone know how to override the red rollover effect just on 'link2'?

http://www.signport.co.uk/test/testsize3.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems with your stylesheet:

Firstly, you're using this `.readmoretext A`. The correct CSS selector for an anchor tag is a lowercase "a", so this needs correcting to `.readmoretext a`.

Once you've done that, add `background-color: transparent;` to your hover rule to remove the red background.

Lastly, you have two `color` properties on your hover rule. Stylesheets cascade, as their name indicates. Since only the last `color` rule will get applied, the first one is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  - @ Wildworx I tried your suggestions and it's done the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Use two different classes for the two different links

Answer (score 0):

Add a CSS rule for the hover property.

Here's a fiddle to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/6cLJ8/

The code causing your problem (in your CSS) is the:

```
a:hover {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Override it with:

```
.readmoretext a:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: I've got a style similar to that on there already:  .readmoretext A:hover {color: #0000CC; text-decoration: underline; color: green;}